# Normal Ordering for Bhabha Scattering

Tags: quantum-field-theory

My QFT text seems to have skipped more steps than I was able to comprehend in my head.  This is for Bhabha Scattering, particularly where an electron and positron annihilate on left side of diagram, to form a virtual photon, and another electron and positron are created on right side of diagram.

Here is the original term:

**(1)** ${\large N[}(\bar\Psi A^\mu\gamma_\mu \Psi)_{x1}(\bar\Psi A^\mu\gamma_\mu \Psi)_{x2} {\large ]}$

N Stands for Normal Ordering. There is a contraction on the $A^\mu\gamma_\mu$ terms, which I  could not figure out how to do in Latex.  x1 and x2 correspond to different times.

Also, $A^\mu\gamma_\mu$, is the A with a Dirac Slash, or A-Slash, which I also could not figure out how to do in Latex.  Would love any tips there too

Anyhow, went from that term to this term:

**(2)** $(\bar\Psi^{-} A^\mu\gamma_\mu \Psi^{-})_{x1}(\bar\Psi^{+} A^\mu\gamma_\mu \Psi^{+})_{x2}$ + ${\large N[}(\bar\Psi^{+} A^\mu\gamma_\mu \Psi^{+})_{x1}(\bar\Psi^{-} A^\mu\gamma_\mu \Psi^{-})_{x2}{\large ]}$

Again, there is a contraction on the A-Slash's, in both the first and second term.  Note the + and - signs now, which stand for the terms that have destruction and creation operators, respectively.  For example:

$\Psi = \Psi^{+} + \Psi^{-} = \Psi^{d} + \Psi^{c}$, and likewise for $\bar\Psi$

Am I missing something obvious going from one term to the next?  It's not like this author to not make each step clear (sorry for the double negative), so I feel like  I am missing something simple here.

Comment: I may have figured this out.  Looks like he just left out a bunch of terms that do not contribute to the process.  But, not totally sure, so would love confirmation that I am correct in my reasoning here.

Comment: Who is the QFT text author? Which page?

Comment: Robert Klauber, I believe.  Student Friendly Quantum Field Theory

Comment: @Qmechanic looks like you may have added on the "Which Page" after I had already replied.  So I missed it, sorry bout that.  Will try and get the page number for you later this evening when I get home.  I do recall that it is in Chapter 8.

Comment: @Qmechanic It's on Page 221 , going from equation (8-25) to (8-26).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I figured this one out.  The author goes through the all the steps for the two different ways Bhabha Scattering can take place.  In each instance, he ignores the terms that do not contribute to the particular process being analyzed.  For example, going from (1) to (2) above in the OP, any terms that do not destroy both the initial electron and positron, and then create an electron and positron later, are left out.  (They would create a state orthogonal to the final state and not contribute to the transition amplitude in the end.)

These were the glossed over steps, although looking closer at the equations in the book, rather than the accompanying text, there is a small note that basically says  "including only terms relevant to the process".  Therefore, going from (1) to (2) looked overly-simplified only due to these missing terms, which would not contribute to the process anyhow.

I figured I would post up this answer in the event anybody else also gets confused by something similar.